# How to merge/push duplicate value in Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js, duplicates

I have an array object like this :

```
[
  {"item_id":1,"name":"DOTA 2 Backpack","image":"XXX","qty":1,"original_price":1450000,"total_price":1450000}, 
  {"item_id":2,"name":"Mobile Legend Backpack","image":"XXX","qty":1,"original_price":1350000,"total_price":1350000}
]
```

When I add this array with the same value will like this:

```
[
  {"item_id":1,"name":"DOTA 2 Backpack","image":"XXX","qty":1,"original_price":1450000,"total_price":1450000},
  {"item_id":2,"name":"Mobile Legend Backpack","image":"XXX","qty":1,"original_price":1350000,"total_price":1350000},
  {"item_id":2,"name":"Mobile Legend Backpack","image":"XXX","qty":1,"original_price":1350000,"total_price":1350000}
]
```

My goal want to the same value will merge like this:

```
    [
  {"item_id":1,"name":"DOTA 2 Backpack","image":"XXX","qty":1,"original_price":1450000,"total_price":1450000},
  {"item_id":2,"name":"Mobile Legend Backpack","image":"XXX","qty":2,"original_price":1350000,"total_price":2700000}
]
```

I'm confused and stuck on it. Please someone help me.

Comment: Are you using lodash?? @Axax

Comment: No, I'm newbie in Javascript by the way.

Comment: No, Item_id is different. 
Example: 
Dota 2 -> item_id : 1
Mobile Legend -> item_id : 2

Comment: No, X is dummy.

Comment: What is your "merge" code?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (items.indexOf(toAdd) != -1)
   items.push(toAdd)
```

or you can use **jQuery grep**, which returns a list of arrays with the asked values

```
if  (($.grep(items, function(e){ return e.id == toAdd.id; })) == 0)
   items.push(toAdd)
```

Comment: Do you know my question ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into this. Might help you .

You can use [Array Iteration methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods)

```
var array1 = [
  {"item_id":X,"name":"DOTA 2 Backpack","image":"XXX","qty":1,"original_price":1450000,"total_price":1450000}, 
  {"item_id":X,"name":"Mobile Legend Backpack","image":"XXX","qty":1,"original_price":1350000,"total_price":1350000}
];

var array2 = [
  {"item_id":X,"name":"DOTA 2 Backpack","image":"XXX","qty":1,"original_price":1450000,"total_price":1450000},
  {"item_id":X,"name":"Mobile Legend Backpack","image":"XXX","qty":1,"original_price":1350000,"total_price":1350000},
  {"item_id":X,"name":"Mobile Legend Backpack","image":"XXX","qty":1,"original_price":1350000,"total_price":1350000}
]

var props = ['name', 'item_id'];

var result = array1.filter(function(o1){

    return !array2.some(function(o2){
        return o1.item_id=== o2.item_id;         
    });
}).map(function(o){

    return props.reduce(function(newo, name){
        newo[name] = o[name];
        return newo;
    }, {});
});
```

Output:

```
[
  {"item_id":X,"name":"DOTA 2 Backpack","image":"XXX","qty":1,"original_price":1450000,"total_price":1450000},
  {"item_id":X,"name":"Mobile Legend Backpack","image":"XXX","qty":1,"original_price":1350000,"total_price":1350000}

]
```

Hope it helps..!

Comment: Have you read the question? This doesn't answer the question, and doesn't give a solution to the OP problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's solved! :)

Comment: @Axaxaxaxax if its solved. Mark it up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push the new `object` to the `array` if it doesn't exist and update it if it exists:

- You need to check for its existence first, using [**Array#some()**
  method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).
- Then update its `qty` and `total_price` using the `found` index.
- Or if it doesn't exist just push it.

This is how should be your code:

```
var found = -1;
if (arr.some(function(el, i) {
    if (el.name === obj.name)
      found = i;
    return el.name === obj.name;
  })) {
  arr[found]["qty"] = arr[found]["qty"] + obj["qty"];
  arr[found]["total_price"] = arr[found]["total_price"] + obj["total_price"];
} else {
  arr.push(obj);
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var arr = [{
    "item_id": 'X',
    "name": "DOTA 2 Backpack",
    "image": "XXX",
    "qty": 1,
    "original_price": 1450000,
    "total_price": 1450000
  },
  {
    "item_id": 'X',
    "name": "Mobile Legend Backpack",
    "image": "XXX",
    "qty": 1,
    "original_price": 1350000,
    "total_price": 1350000
  }
];

var obj = {
  "item_id": 'X',
  "name": "Mobile Legend Backpack",
  "image": "XXX",
  "qty": 1,
  "original_price": 1350000,
  "total_price": 1350000
};
var found = -1;
if (arr.some(function(el, i) {
    if (el.name === obj.name)
      found = i;
    return el.name === obj.name;
  })) {
  arr[found]["qty"] = arr[found]["qty"] + obj["qty"];
  arr[found]["total_price"] = arr[found]["total_price"] + obj["total_price"];
} else {
  arr.push(obj);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's solved! :)

Comment: @Axaxaxaxax You are welcome, glad it helps. You can accept the aswer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).. In the code example I am doing comparison with element's `item_id`.

Code:

```js
const array = [{"item_id": 1,"name":"DOTA 2 Backpack","image":"XXX","qty":1,"original_price":1450000,"total_price":1450000}, {"item_id":2,"name":"Mobile Legend Backpack","image":"XXX","qty":1,"original_price":1350000,"total_price":1350000}];
const newVal = {"item_id": 2,"name":"Mobile Legend Backpack","image":"XXX","qty":1,"original_price":1350000,"total_price":1350000};

const addElement = (arr, val) => {
  return arr.reduce((a, c, i) => {
    if (c['item_id'] === val['item_id']) {
      a.found = true;
      c.qty += val.qty;
    }
    
    a.result.push(c);
    
    return !a.found && i + 1 === arr.length
      ? [].concat(arr.result, val)
      : a;
  }, {result: [], found: false});
};


console.log(addElement(array, newVal).result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's solved! :)